# Select a row from a data frame with the least number of NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, select, row

So I have a block of text that I've seperated into a vector, and from each line of vector I've further seperated it into a data frame. In a perfect world, every row of the DF would be exactly the same, but it's not and there a number of rows with NA values in them. What I need to do is select the row from the data frame with the least number of NA values.

So say the DF looked like this:

> Name Year NA Address NA State NA
>   Name Year ID Address City State Rank
>   Name Year NA NA       City State NA
>   Name NA NA NA NA NA Rank
>   Name Year NA NA NA NA NA

Where they each belong to column. So I need a way to identify which row has the least number of NA's, and then select that row's elements. So ultimately I want the return to just be single row DF (or a vector preferably) that reads

> Name Year ID Address City State Rank

In this case, row 2.

I know that:

> max( rowSums(!is.na(x)) )

Will return me the row# with the most number of not-na values, but I can't seem to figure out how to grab the elements of that row. I was thinking using which() would work, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for your help!

David

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your data frame is `df`, then:

```
df[which.max(rowSums(!is.na(df))),]
```

Should return the single-row data frame with the fewest NAs.

Comment: You're exactly right! I tried something very similar to that, but it looks like I must have had my syntax wrong. Thank you so much! PS. it doesn't let me upvote since my rep is so low, but just know I would if I could!

Comment: Glad to help. You should still be able to select this as the "right" answer for you  even if you can't vote.